# MSSQL server cuts down responses from SphinxQL connected through MySQL ODBC driver

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sphinx

**What I have:**
Sphinx(2.2.3) that connected by Linked Server to MS SQL Server 2012 by means of MySQL ODBC 5.1

**Problem:**
All the responses from function "Call Snippets" are cut down to 85 symbols even breaking snippets tag. Limit parameter won't change this strange behavior. It is likely to be some MS SQL option 'cause if I call it directly via MySQL console response is correct.

**I call it like this:**

```
EXEC ('CALL SNIPPETS('text1 test text2 text3 test text4 text5 test text6 text7 test text8 text9 test text10 text11 test text12 text13 test text14 text15 test text16','index','test', 1 AS query_mode, 100 as limit')') AT Sphinx
```

**I get an answer like this:**

```
  ...  <b>test</b> text10 text11 <b>test</b> text12 text13 <b>test</b> text14 text15 <
```

As you can see tag last is broken and string is cutted down to 85 symbols.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know exactly, but utf-8 has 3-bits kode. 255/3 = 85. If you use other kode, for example cp1251 (1 bit), pay attenyion for it. I have similar problem when use SphinxQL.